# Symmetry of concentration bounds on mean

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, measure-concentration

**Question summary:**

If I have a two-sided bound, can I immediately get a one-sided bound with tighter constants?

**Question details:**

Let $\mathbf X = X_1,...,X_n$ be $n$ i.i.d. real-valued random variables where $X_i \in [a,b]$ and $\mu = \mathbf E[X_1]$. For $\delta\in(0,1)$, let $f(\mathbf X, \delta)$ be a function such that:

$$
\Pr\left (\left | \mu -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right | \leq f(\mathbf X, \delta) \right ) \geq 1-\delta \tag{*}
$$

For example, if using Hoeffding's inequality, then $f(\mathbf X, \delta) := (b-a)\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1/\delta)}{2n}}$. However, we do not assume that $f$ uses Hoeffding's inequality -  it is any $f$ that makes the above equation hold given our assumptions.

The question: Can we conclude that therefore the one-sided bound also holds with $f/2$? That is:

$$
\Pr\left ( \mu -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i  \leq \frac{1}{2}f(\mathbf X, \delta) \right ) \geq 1-\delta \tag{**}
$$

This holds for Hoeffding's inequality, but does it hold in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is negative. Indeed, for simplicity, let $a=-1$ and $b=1$.

In the case when $\delta=1/10$, $n=1$, and $X_1$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$ (so that $\mu=0$), let $f(\mathbf X,\delta):=1-1/10$. 
Then 
$
\Pr\left (\left | \mu -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right | \leq f(\mathbf X, \delta) \right ) =
\Pr(|X_1|\le1-1/10) = 1-1/10=1-\delta
$,
so that $(*)$ holds -- 
whereas 
$$
\Pr\left ( \mu -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i  \leq \frac{1}{2}f(\mathbf X, \delta) \right )
=\Pr\left(X_1\ge-\frac12\,(1-1/10)\right)=29/40 
$$
$$\not\geq 1-1/10=1-\delta
,$$ 
so that $(**)$ fails to hold.

In all cases other than the one just considered, let e.g. $f(\mathbf X, \delta) := b-a$, so that $(*)$ hold.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. What did you mean by the last line of your answer? Yes, that $f$ makes $(*)$ hold, but why do you bring this up?

Comment: I thought you wanted $f(\mathbf X, \delta)$ to be defined for all $n$, $\mathbf X=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$, and $\delta\in(0,1)$. That is why I wrote the last line, to complement the definition of $f(\mathbf X, \delta)$ in the particular case considered first.

Comment: Ah, I see - "all cases other than the one considered" is referring to $n>1$. Thanks.

Comment: More precisely, "all cases other than the one considered" refers to the negation of the conjunction of the conditions that $\delta=1/10$, $n=1$, and $X_1$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$.